# I'm Facing this issue "The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?"

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

How to fix this issue?

```
error: The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?
error: The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?
error: The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?
error: The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option. Is there a typo?
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated, dagger.fastInit, dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType]'
```

This is my build file. After adding     id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") I'm facing this issue. If I remove that line I'm facing another issue public final class AppController extends android. app.Application {
^
Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)

````
plugins {
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.boscosoft.audit.sapt"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.boscosoft.audit.sapt"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding =true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    //SDP library for dimensions
    implementation ("com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0")

    //Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5")

    //ViewModel & LiveData
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
    //Stetho Debug library
    implementation ("com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1")
    implementation ("com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1")
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}```
````